# getting Invalid argument error in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Designing an application in CI and came across this strange issue. Below is controller

```
$list = $this->client->get_datatables();

    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];


        foreach ($list as $client) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $client=(array)$client;
        $row[] = isset($client['name'])?$client['name']:"---";
        $row[] = isset($client['city'])?$client['city']:"---";
        $row[] = isset($client['amount_due'])?"Rs.".$client['amount_due']:"Rs.00.00";
        $row[] = isset($client['lastdispatch'])?$client['lastdispatch']:"---";
        $row[] = isset($client['lastbill'])?$client['lastbill']:"--";
        $row[] = isset($client['lastpayment'])?$client['lastpayment']:"---";
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    //"recordsTotal" => $this->person->count_all(),
                    //"recordsFiltered" => $this->person->count_filtered(),
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->client->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->client->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );

    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Below is modal

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Client_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'invoices';
    var $column_order = array('invoices.amoount_due'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('amoount_due'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable
    var $order = array('invoices.amoount_due' => 'desc'); // default order 
    //public function __construct()
    //{
        //parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->database();
    //}

    public function _get_datatables_query()
    {
        //$this->db->select( 'client.id , client.name, client.uniqueid, //client.reg_date, client.paydue, client.lastdispatch, //client.lastbill, client.lastpayment, client.address, client.city, //client.phone, client.email, client.private, client.billing, //client.transport1, client.transport2, client.tin, client.remarks, //client.status, client.block_status');
        //$this->db->from('client');
        //$this->db->join('invoices', 'client.uniqueid = invoices.uniqueid');
        //$this->db->group_by('invoices.uniqueid');
//$this->db->from($this->table);


//$this->db->select('*');
//$this->db->from($this->table);
//$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('join', 'left', 'invoices.uniqueid = client.uniqueid');
//$sub->select('invoices.amount_due')->from('invoices');
//$sub->db->order_by('invoices.id','DESC');
//$sub->db->limit(1);
//$this->subquery->end_subquery('invoices');

//$this->db->select('invoices.id','invoices.uniqueid','invoices.pastamount_due',invoices.dispatch_date,invoices.bill_date,invoices.paymentdate, client.name );
//$this->db->from('invoices');
//$sub = $this->subquery->start_subquery('join', 'left', 'invoices.uniqueid = client.uniqueid');
//$sub->select('invoices.amount_due')->from('invoices');


//select inv2.id,inv1.uniqueid,inv2.pastamount_due,inv2.dispatch_date,inv2.bill_date,inv2.paymentdate, c.name 
//FROM invoices as inv2 
//join (SELECT max(id) as maxid, uniqueid from invoices GROUP by uniqueid ) as inv1
//on (inv2.id =inv1.maxid and inv2.uniqueid = inv1.uniqueid) 
//JOIN client as c 
//ON inv2.uniqueid = c.uniqueid
$sql = "select inv2.id,inv1.uniqueid,inv2.pastamount_due, c.name 
        FROM invoices as inv2 
        JOIN (SELECT max(id) as maxid, uniqueid from invoices GROUP by uniqueid)
        as inv1 on (inv2.id=inv1.maxid and inv2.uniqueid=inv1.uniqueid) 
        JOIN client as c ON inv2.uniqueid = c.uniqueid";

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if($query !== false)
{
   return $query->result();
}

return NULL; //$query is false. Probably due to bad syntax in the query string

        $i = 0;
        // var_dump($this->column_search );

        foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
        {  

            if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
            {

                if($i===0) // first loop
                {
                    $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                    $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                }

                if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                    $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
        {
            $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        } 
        else if(isset($this->order))
        {
            $order = $this->order;
            $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
        }
    }

    function get_datatables()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        if($_POST['length'] != -1)
        $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        //$query = $this->db->get();
        //return $query->result();
    }

    function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->where('client.id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row();
    }

    public function save($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }

    public function update($where, $data)
    {
        $this->db->update($this->table, $data, $where);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

    public function delete_by_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('client.id', $id);
        $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

    public function fetch_client(){
        $this->db->select('name,uniqueid');
        //$this->db->distinct('id');
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->order_by("name");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();    
    }

}
```

While compiling the application I am invalid argument error in controller for each line. I am not sure where I am going wrong as instead of using get() I am returning the query result.Can someone please help !!!

Comment: why have you put comment in `get_datatables()`? Remove this comments `//$query = $this->db->get();
        //return $query->result();`

Comment: It can be due to there is no data in $list. 
Please  check that either $list is empty? If it is empty then this error can come.

Comment: The return statement is in comment: get_datatables() function of your model

Comment: @Pragya If I uncomment this then the error comes uo stating that no table is selected as I have written sql query differently.

Comment: @JignaJain Try to print last query byt using $this->db->last_query() in _get_datatables_query() function of model. And run that query in database sql tab. I think by using this step you get the exact error.

Comment: @Pragya Query is running absolutely fine and now its giving me error 'No table used'